# Advice on how to model this piece of a chair?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, bezier-curves

I'm trying to model the [Yksi Chair](https://www.fredericia.com/products/yksi-3/by-designer-thau-kallio.aspx?PID=63&catid=12683) from the Fredericia website. I've modelled a couple other simpler pieces of furniture, and I'm doing this for practice. I can do pretty much everything, but I'm struggling with the backrest on this chair. Here are some more photos of the chair for reference:

[image]
[image]

I've gone through BlenderGuru's chair modeling tutorial, and I tried applying the same techniques (mirror mod, use plane to outline shape, subsurf mod, solidify mod) but I just can't seem to get it right. I've also tried making the basic curve of the top part with a bezier curve, converting to a mesh, and then extruding the points down and repositioning/scaling them to fit the bottom. It's *okay* so far, but it still doesn't look straight and even like it does in the photos. The "arm" portions of mine always somehow get twisted or warped along the way, and it doesn't look like one uniform piece like it should. In my current attempt (there have been many) I have it as good as I can get, but then that little nubby bit that connects to the legs is also giving me problems. I can never seem to extrude it in the right direction, and I have to resort to snapping it along one of the edges until it looks good enough.

Can anyone offer tips or advice on how to model a piece like that? What method do you go for?

Here's my .blend file:
[image]

Comment: I should note that I'm specifically having a hard time keeping the smooth curve throughout the whole backrest, whilst also have that inwards slant that goes towards the seat. When I try the solidify mod, it solidifies it, but it doesn't solidify along a particular axis, so when I try to apply a slant to the seat, it "twists" the entire thing, which doesn't look good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you should simply extrude a plane along the shape, in front, left and top view, then extrude inwards, then bevel, etc...

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your numerous screenshot examples.. This helps me a lot. I don't know why I couldn't make it look nice using this method, but I just tried it again right now and it's much better this time. Is this a fairly recommended method for simple furniture? plane, extrude, outline shape, then extrude again (similar to solidify mod?) and adjust as necessary?

Comment: sometimes it may have some advantages to use other methods, like using bezier curve or else, but I think that if you can stay simple with a simple plane, some extrusions and bevels, it's the way to go. You need to begin with as few vertices as possible in order to make the whole shape good, otherwise you make any correction a bit tedious.